# Is it necessary to use addTestDevice?

Tags: java, android, admob

I am using testAd ID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712) from admob not my admob ID, do I need to use addTestDevice() too while testing in mobile device?
It was even showing testAds screen, not the live ads.

Because I did this, and I used my app whole day for testing purpose, and I got account suspension mail at night.

```
Interstitial mInterstitial= new InterstitialAd(this);

    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use addTestDevice () while using test ids. You only need it when you are using the live ads. There might be some other reason for your account suspension. Test ad ids have no link to your admob account.

Check the details here https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

As they have clearly mentioned 
"The quickest way to enable testing is to use Google-provided test ad units. These ad units are not associated with your AdMob account, so there's no risk of your account generating invalid traffic when using these ad units"